# How to get multiple value from AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

any superior can guide me how to return multiple value from php using AJAX, like below. i have using the json_encode, but still cannot working. Thanks a lot.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 var btnValue = document.querySelectorAll('#btn');

  for (var i = 0; i < btnValue.length; i++) {
  
   btnValue[i].onclick = function() {

       var btnValue = $(this).attr('value');

       var textboxValue = $("#textboxValue").val();
       var textboxValue2 = $("#textboxValue2").val();

       $.get('AJAX_function.php', {
           sendtextboxValue: textboxValue,
            sendtextboxValue2: textboxValue2,
       }, function(data) {
              
              //my question is, how to return multiple value in AJAX
          $('#column').html(data);
           
       });
   }
}
```

```html
<?php
echo 'value1';
echo 'value2';
echo 'value3';

?>
```

Comment: in your return Json( data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet ); , as long as you're attaching all the data to your data variable, you can return whatever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the values in an array, and use `json_encode()`.

PHP:

```
$result = array('x' => 'value1', 'y' => 'value2', 'z' => 'value3');
```

Then use `$.getJSON` to get the result and parse it.

```
$.getJSON('AJAX_function.php', {
    sendtextboxValue: textboxValue,
    sendtextboxValue2: textboxValue2,
}, function(data) {
    $("#column1").html(data.x);
    $("#column2").html(data.y);
    $("#column3").html(data.z);
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer me. what should I coding in between function(data){ }, if I want purely refresh a div? appreciate for your answer.

Comment: What do you want to refresh it with? You could do something like `$("#column").text("X = " + data.x + " Y = " + data.y + " Z = " + data.z);` for instance.

Comment: Thank a lot for your helpful answer